# React Native: Navigating Between Screens (typescript)

Tags: typescript, react-native

Good morning,

I am developing a react native app. I want to make a toy example to understand the navegation, but I cannot recreate the documentation example.

An image of the output of the simulation:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elM5b.png)

The code that I tried:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, SafeAreaView, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator, NativeStackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Index from './components/IndexView';
type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Profile: { name: string };
};

type HomeScreenProps = {
  navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Home'>;
};

const HomeScreen: React.FC<HomeScreenProps> = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Button
      title="Go to Jane's profile"
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })}
    />
  );
};

type ProfileScreenProps = {
  navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Profile'>;
  route: { params: { name: string } };
};

const ProfileScreen: React.FC<ProfileScreenProps> = ({ route }) => {
  return <Text>This is {route.params.name}'s profile</Text>;
};

const MemoizedProfileScreen = React.memo(ProfileScreen); // Wrap ProfileScreen with React.memo

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

function App(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{ title: 'Welcome' }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Profile"
            component={MemoizedProfileScreen} // Use MemoizedProfileScreen here
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved using:

```js
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';
const navigation = useNavigation();
onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('Home')}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).